# Java SSH connect with key using JSch - Auth Failed

Tags: java, authentication, ssh, jsch, ssh-keys

I'm trying to connect to localhost using SSH with key. But I still get an error:

> Auth Failed

Here is the method implementation:

```
public void downloadUsingPublicKey(String username, String host)
{
     String privateKey = "~/.ssh/id_rsa";
     
     JSch jsch = new JSch(); 
     Session session = null; 
     Channel channel = null; 
     ChannelSftp channelSftp = null; 
     try 
     { 
         jsch.addIdentity(privateKey); 
         System.out.println("Private Key Added."); 
         
         session = jsch.getSession(username, host); 
         System.out.println("session created."); 
         
         java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
         config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); 
         
         session.setConfig(config); 
         session.connect(); 
         
         channel = session.openChannel("sftp"); 
         channel.connect(); System.out.println("shell channel connected...."); 
         
         channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel; 
         channelSftp.cd(Config.dir); 
         
         System.out.println("Changed the directory..."); 
     } catch (JSchException e) 
     { 
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
     } catch (SftpException e) 
     { 
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
     }finally
     { 
         if(channelSftp!=null)
         { 
             channelSftp.disconnect(); 
             channelSftp.exit(); 
         } 
         if(channel!=null) channel.disconnect(); 
         if(session!=null) session.disconnect(); 
     } 
}
```

I've created my public/private key pair using Linux terminal, as follows:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@email.com"
```

I didn't put any phrase.

Next step:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And finally

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then when I run my program I get error:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:512)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at pl.eroj.filedownloader.Downloader.downloadUsingPublicKey(Downloader.java:73)
    at pl.eroj.filedownloader.Downloader.main(Downloader.java:107)
```

Any ideas? My key is of OpenSSH type starting with line
"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

Comment: You need to add the client's (new) public key to the `authorized_keys` file **ON THE SERVER**

Comment: So if i get it correctly I need to copy the key from id_rsa.pub and paste it in the .ssh/authorized_keys on the server ?

Comment: copy&paste can work, as long as the result is one long line exactly as it is in the source file id_rsa.pub; depending on the terminals/UIs you use they might turn displayed line wraps into line breaks. A simple robust way is to `scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub user@host:.` then `ssh` to the server and `cat` the copy onto `authorized_keys` and check/fix the permissions (must be inaccessible to other users). Or if you don't yet have anything (needed) in server `authorized_keys` just chmod the local file and directly `scp -p .ssh/id_rsa.pub user@host:.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Yeah i used this method with scp and it all worked out :) so the problem was solved. Thanks for advice

Comment: Here is the blog article explaining how to connect to remote host by using public key authentication from java: http://www.svlada.com/ssh-public-key-authentication/

Comment: Related question: [Public key authentication fails with JSch but work with OpenSSH with the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72743823/850848).

Answer (score 2):

This how I connected localy using with **Path of private Key**
when
*privateKeyPath ="C:\Keys\private_key.ppk"*

```
    public static OutputStream ConnectionUsingKey(String user, String hostName, String privateKeyPath)
        throws JSchException, IOException {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;
    try {

        jsch.addIdentity(privateKeyPath);
        session = jsch.getSession(user, hostName, 22);
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.connect();
        if (session.isConnected() == true) {
            System.out.println("Connection to Session server is successfully");
        }
        channel = session.openChannel("shell");
        channel.setInputStream(System.in);
        channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
        channel.connect(30 * 1000);
        return channel.getOutputStream();

    } catch (JSchException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create Jsch Session object.", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Vladi.
In my case I needed to connect to a server that used both private key and a password. Hence I had to set the Config like this

```
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,password");
        session.setPassword("some_password");
```