# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail at runtime

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, jsch

I am trying to connect amazon ec2 instance with the help Java JSCH library version: 0.1.55 with jdk 19. I am able to login manually via putty and cmd but when I am logging in through Java then I am getting following exception

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar:na]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar:na]
    at com.example.CloudRESTAPI.Service.CloudRESTServiceImpl.executeCommands(CloudRESTServiceImpl.java:136) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.CloudRESTAPI.Controller.MyController.commandsCall(MyController.java:67) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
```

Here is my Java Source code to connect to ec2 instance via Jsch

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.addIdentity("D:\\Keys\\EC2CheckKey.pem");
Session session=jsch.getSession("ec2-user", "13.48.47.179", 22);
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect(); // Exception Occuring
System.out.println("Connected");
```

Comment: See [Public key authentication fails with JSch but work with OpenSSH with the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72743823/850848).

Comment: What changes should I make to run the code?

Comment: What is unclear about my answer to the linked question?

Comment: Okay, yeah I got it I replaced my maven dependency with https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mwiede/jsch/0.1.61. Thank you for your suggestion.