# SFTP Connection through OPENSSH IdentityFile in Java

Tags: java, rsa, sftp, jsch

I'm developing a Java application that has to store data inside an SFTP.

The test environment has a password authentication, meanwhile the production environment has an authorized OPENSSH key (the standard `id_rsa`) used as `IdentityFile`. This means that I have to keep both authentication methods in the same code.

That's how I handled it. Basically, if the `identityFile` path is not set, it will leverage the password login. Note that all variables come from `application.properties`:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.setKnownHosts(knownHosts);

if (!identityFile.equals("")) {
    jsch.addIdentity(identityFile, passphrase);
}
Session jschSession = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
jschSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

if (identityFile.equals("")) {
    jschSession.setPassword(pass);
    jschSession.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
} else {
    jschSession.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
}
jschSession.connect();
ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
channelSftp.connect();
```

I can connect to the test environment but cannot connect to the production SFTP, so I instantiated an SFTP on a development server with (hopefully) the same configurations. I followed [this](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/configuration/set-up-an-ubuntu-sftp-server/) guide.

Connecting to the development SFTP through shell and FileZilla, specifying the `IdentityFile`, works fine. Connecting to the test SFTP through Java, shell and FileZilla with password, works fine.

Java won't connect using `IdentityFile`. All I keep getting is `com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: Auth fail` on `jschSession.connect()`, if I use an RSA private key.

Production environment uses an OPENSSH private key, so I cannot convert it. If I use the OPENSSH key, I get `invalid privatekey: [B@48c76607` error, on `jsch.addIdentity(identityFile)`. As I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134212/invalid-privatekey-when-using-jsch), `JSch` doesn't like OPENSSH keys.

This means that JSch wants an RSA key, but it doesn't connect either. I will think about converting the OPENSSH to RSA later.

I tried running the `jar` on both Windows and an Ubuntu dockerized VM. The `id_rsa` file has the right permissions on both systems.

The version of `JSch` I'm using is `jsch-0.1.55.jar`. I'm running `Java 8`.

These are the JSch logs after connecting with an RSA key.

```
Connecting to <HOST> port <PORT>
Connection established
Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.3
Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
kex: server: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
kex: server: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
kex: server: 
kex: server: 
kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
kex: client: none
kex: client: none
kex: client: 
kex: client: 
kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent
expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
Host '<HOST>' is known and matches the ECDSA host key
SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Authentications that can continue: publickey
Next authentication method: publickey
Disconnecting from <HOST> port <PORT>
```

Realistically, there is something missing in my SSH/SFTP configuration, since my app can't connect to SSH on the same server either.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MartinPrikryl and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72771323/11961036) linked thread, I found a solution. Looks like someone forked the original `jsch` library and solved these kind of problems. Swapping the Maven dependency from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.55</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mwiede</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

was enough to solve it. Absolutely no need to refactor code.

### Some considerations

This library is a thid-party, independent fork from the original `jsch`. This means it may still have some flaws and they could stop supporting it anytime (just like `com.jcraft`). Personally, I would have preferred an actual fix, but solving it was too urgent. Plus, this fork allows me to use an `OPENSSH` key. Using a converted RSA key could have been a problem, since I would avoid touching any of the production environment configurations.